# Python. Продублировать одну картинку несколько раз

Tags: python, изображения

Есть 1 картинка (допустим, https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3xfv.jpg). Я хочу сделать так, чтобы она повторялась 5 раз по горизонтали и 3 раз по вертикали (должно получиться что-то вроде этого: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCF4p.jpg)

Сам я никогда в питоне с картинками не работал, а в интернете нашел только, как сделать фильтры для изображения.

Comment: Довольно просто с помощью [pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html). Читаете картинку, получаете её размеры. Создаете новую картинку, с размерами, кратными исходной. В цикле копируете исходную картинку и в итоге полученную мозаику сохраняете. [Пример](https://github.com/vladimirgamalyan/pictools/blob/master/multiply.py).

Comment: хотите зделать ГДЕ? в desktop UI, web UI, или может нужно сгенерить картинку такую, содержащую 5x3 исходную картинку? на все эти хотелки разные инструменты. 
Если нужно картинку сгенерить - OpenCV намного удобнее чем Pillow, как по мне

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan , сделайте в виде ответа :)

Answer (score 4):

[Используя](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/210f9854d1fdb8f299193c83cad3c2a33c29b35d/pil_example/img_to_grid/main.py) `pillow`:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("img.jpg")
width, height = image.size

ROW_COUNT = 3
COLUMN_COUNT = 5

grid_image = Image.new("RGB", (width * COLUMN_COUNT, height * ROW_COUNT), (255, 255, 255))

for row in range(ROW_COUNT):
    y = row * width

    for column in range(COLUMN_COUNT):
        x = column * height
        grid_image.paste(image, (x, y))

# grid_image.show()
grid_image.save('grid_img.jpg')
```

3x5:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

[Используя](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/e9849e323bf7c197ffe65a497aa5d9d3b6536880/qt_img_to_grid/main.py) `Qt`:

```
try:
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPainter, QColor
except:
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QImage, QPainter


image = QImage("img.jpg")
size = image.size()
width, height = size.width(), size.height()

ROW_COUNT = 3
COLUMN_COUNT = 5

grid_image = QImage(width * COLUMN_COUNT, height * ROW_COUNT, QImage.Format_RGB32)
grid_image.fill(QColor('white'))

painter = QPainter(grid_image)

for row in range(ROW_COUNT):
    y = row * width

    for column in range(COLUMN_COUNT):
        x = column * height
        painter.drawImage(x, y, image)

grid_image.save('grid_img.jpg')
```

3x5:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]